# Email Alert flow not getting the right lead status

Tags: visual-workflow

Requirements: create a flow to alert the lead owner when the lead status is not changing in 7 days.

My formula for decision: {!$Record.CreatedDate} + 7

I created a flow to send an email alert when a lead owner is not changing lead status in 7 days. Firstly the flow worked fine, and I got the correct lead record (A) with Open status. But when I changed lead A status to Contacted and another lead B's status to Open, flow only got show A record.

Also, I set the status condition equal to Open, but when I debugged, it turned to Working like the image below. Can you guys help me? Is there something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, you'll probably want to dig in to the specific requirements of your user: (a) "tell me if the status hasn't changed in the last 7 days" is different from (b) "tell me if the status hasn't changed from the default-on-creation status in 7 days", which in turn is different from (c) "the status should progress from one stage to the next within 7 days, *each time*, and you should tell me if it doesn't". Or (d) something else entirely.

Using "created date + 7" works for (b), but only (b). Also, given that in the screenshot you've set up a *scheduled* flow rather than a *record-triggered* flow, it's going to keep sending your user email on day 7, 8, 9, and so on.
I'd recommend setting it up more as follows:
[image: Image of example flow]

If the desired outcome is actually (a) or (c), a record-triggered flow is still your best bet, but you need to combine it with a custom date field you can use to timestamp whenever the status changes (in the "immediately" logic branch for the above screenshot). Then instead of referencing the created date or the status, you check if the *timestamp* is 7 days ago or not, and send the email if it is.